# Numpy: use reshape or newaxis to add dimensions

Tags: python, numpy

Either `ndarray.reshape` or `numpy.newaxis` can be used to add a new dimension to an array.  They both seem to create a view, is there any reason or advantage to use one instead of the other?

```
>>> b
array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])
>>> c = b.reshape((1,4))
>>> c *= 2
>>> c
array([[ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.]])
>>> c.shape
(1, 4)
>>> b
array([ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.])
>>> d = b[np.newaxis,...]
>>> d
array([[ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.]])
>>> d.shape
(1, 4)
>>> d *= 2
>>> b
array([ 4.,  4.,  4.,  4.])
>>> c
array([[ 4.,  4.,  4.,  4.]])
>>> d
array([[ 4.,  4.,  4.,  4.]])
>>>
```

`

Comment: `b.reshape(1,-1)` is handy shortcut.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I don't see evidence of much difference.  You could do a time test on very large arrays.  Basically both fiddle with the shape, and possibly the strides.  `__array_interface__` is a nice way of accessing this information.  For example:

```
In [94]: b.__array_interface__
Out[94]: 
{'data': (162400368, False),
 'descr': [('', '<f8')],
 'shape': (5,),
 'strides': None,
 'typestr': '<f8',
 'version': 3}

In [95]: b[None,:].__array_interface__
Out[95]: 
{'data': (162400368, False),
 'descr': [('', '<f8')],
 'shape': (1, 5),
 'strides': (0, 8),
 'typestr': '<f8',
 'version': 3}

In [96]: b.reshape(1,5).__array_interface__
Out[96]: 
{'data': (162400368, False),
 'descr': [('', '<f8')],
 'shape': (1, 5),
 'strides': None,
 'typestr': '<f8',
 'version': 3}
```

Both create a view, using the same `data` buffer as the original.  Same shape, but reshape doesn't change the `strides`.  `reshape` lets you specify the `order`.

And `.flags` shows differences in the `C_CONTIGUOUS` flag.

`reshape` may be faster because it is making fewer changes.  But either way the operation shouldn't affect the time of larger calculations much.

e.g. for large `b`

```
In [123]: timeit np.outer(b.reshape(1,-1),b)
1 loops, best of 3: 288 ms per loop
In [124]: timeit np.outer(b[None,:],b)
1 loops, best of 3: 287 ms per loop
```

---

Interesting observation that: `b.reshape(1,4).strides -> (32, 8)`

Here's my guess.  `.__array_interface__` is displaying an underlying attribute, and `.strides` is more like a property (though it may all be buried in C code).  The default underlying value is `None`, and when needed for calculation (or display with `.strides`) it calculates it from the shape and item size. `32` is the distance to the end of the 1st row (4x8).  `np.ones((2,4)).strides` has the same `(32,8)` (and `None` in `__array_interface__`.

`b[None,:]` on the other hand is preparing the array for broadcasting.  When broadcasted, existing values are used repeatedly.  That's what the `0` in `(0,8)` does.

```
In [147]: b1=np.broadcast_arrays(b,np.zeros((2,1)))[0]

In [148]: b1.shape
Out[148]: (2, 5000)

In [149]: b1.strides
Out[149]: (0, 8)

In [150]: b1.__array_interface__
Out[150]: 
{'data': (3023336880L, False),
 'descr': [('', '<f8')],
 'shape': (2, 5),
 'strides': (0, 8),
 'typestr': '<f8',
 'version': 3}
```

`b1` displays the same as `np.ones((2,5))` but has only 5 items.

`np.broadcast_arrays` is a function in `/numpy/lib/stride_tricks.py`.  It uses `as_strided` from the same file.  These functions directly play with the shape and strides attributes.

Comment: Cool, ...  ```__array_interface__```. !!

Comment: Hmmm   ```b.reshape(1,4).strides  -> (32, 8)```, ```b[None,...].strides ->(0, 8)```

Comment: Interesting.  I've added some thoughts on that.

Comment: ```...preparing the array for broadcasting``` sounds right. So the zero for the first stride dimension/value kind of forces it to *start from the beginning*  during broadcasting.  that might explain the ```C_CONTIGUOUS``` difference also.

Answer (score 33):

One reason to use `numpy.newaxis` over `ndarray.reshape` is when you have more than one "unknown" dimension to operate with. So, for example, for the following array:

```
>>> arr.shape
(10, 5)
```

This works:

```
>>> arr[:, np.newaxis, :].shape
(10, 1, 5)
```

But this does not:

```
>>> arr.reshape(-1, 1, -1)
...
ValueError: can only specify one unknown dimension
```

Comment: What about None and expand_dims?