# Numpy: get 1D array as 2D array without reshape

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have need for hstacking multple arrays with with the same number of rows (although the number of rows is variable between uses) but different number of columns.  However some of the arrays only have one column, eg.

```
array = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
```

which gives

```
#array.shape = (5,)
```

but I'd like to have the shape recognized as a 2d array, eg.

```
#array.shape = (5,1)
```

So that hstack can actually combine them.
My current solution is:

```
array = np.atleast_2d([1,2,3,4,5]).T
#array.shape = (5,1)
```

So I was wondering, is there a better way to do this? Would

```
array = np.array([1,2,3,4,5]).reshape(len([1,2,3,4,5]), 1)
```

be better? 
Note that my use of [1,2,3,4,5] is just a toy list to make the example concrete.  In practice it will be a much larger list passed into a function as an argument. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the code of `hstack` and `vstack`.  One, or both of those, pass the arguments through `atleast_nd`.  That is a perfectly acceptable way of reshaping an array.

Some other ways:

```
arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5]).reshape(-1,1)  # saves the use of len()
arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])[:,None]  # adds a new dim at end
np.array([1,2,3],ndmin=2).T  # used by column_stack
```

---

`hstack` and `vstack` transform their inputs with:

```
arrs = [atleast_1d(_m) for _m in tup]
[atleast_2d(_m) for _m in tup]
```

---

test data:

```
a1=np.arange(2)
a2=np.arange(10).reshape(2,5)
a3=np.arange(8).reshape(2,4)

np.hstack([a1.reshape(-1,1),a2,a3])
np.hstack([a1[:,None],a2,a3])
np.column_stack([a1,a2,a3])
```

result:

```
array([[0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3],
       [1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 7]])
```

If you don't know ahead of time which arrays are 1d, then `column_stack` is easiest to use.  The others require a little function that tests for dimensionality before applying the reshaping.

[Numpy: use reshape or newaxis to add dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28385666/numpy-use-reshape-or-newaxis-to-add-dimensions)

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about these two ways.  I will try those with some timing tests to see which performs best, but both seem less contrived than my method.  Thanks!

Comment: I added a link to a recent related SO question.

Comment: The latest version has added a more general purpose `stack`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your intent correctly, you wish to convert an array of shape (N,) to an array of shape (N,1) so that you can apply `np.hstack`:

```
In [147]: np.hstack([np.atleast_2d([1,2,3,4,5]).T, np.atleast_2d([1,2,3,4,5]).T])
Out[147]: 
array([[1, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [3, 3],
       [4, 4],
       [5, 5]])
```

In that case, you could use avoid reshaping the arrays and use [`np.column_stack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html) instead:

```
In [151]: np.column_stack([[1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5]])
Out[151]: 
array([[1, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [3, 3],
       [4, 4],
       [5, 5]])
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually using this with scikit-learn so and they use hstack internally so I do need them to be row-oriented.

Answer (score 1):

I followed Ludo's work and just changed the size of v from 5 to 10000. I ran the code on my PC and the result shows that atleast_2d seems to be a more efficient method in the larger scale case.

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

v = np.arange(10000)

print('atleast2d:',timeit.timeit(lambda:np.atleast_2d(v).T))
print('reshape:',timeit.timeit(lambda:np.array(v).reshape(-1,1)))  # saves the use of len()
print('v[:,None]:', timeit.timeit(lambda:np.array(v)[:,None]))  # adds a new dim at end
print('np.array(v,ndmin=2).T:', timeit.timeit(lambda:np.array(v,ndmin=2).T))  # used by column_stack
```

The result is:

```
atleast2d: 1.3809496470021259
reshape: 27.099974197000847
v[:,None]: 28.58291715100131
np.array(v,ndmin=2).T: 30.141663907001202
```

My suggestion is that use [:None] when dealing with a short vector and np.atleast_2d when your vector goes longer.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add info on hpaulj's answer. I was curious about how fast were the four methods described. The winner is the method adding a column at the end of the 1d array.

Here is what I ran:

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

v = [1,2,3,4,5]

print('atleast2d:',timeit.timeit(lambda:np.atleast_2d(v).T))
print('reshape:',timeit.timeit(lambda:np.array(v).reshape(-1,1)))  # saves the use of len()
print('v[:,None]:', timeit.timeit(lambda:np.array(v)[:,None]))  # adds a new dim at end
print('np.array(v,ndmin=2).T:', timeit.timeit(lambda:np.array(v,ndmin=2).T))  # used by column_stack
```

And the results:

```
atleast2d: 4.455070924214851
reshape: 2.0535152913971615
v[:,None]: 1.8387219828073285
np.array(v,ndmin=2).T: 3.1735243063353664
```