# Vector * Vector (Matrix multiplication)

Tags: python, numpy

I want to do the following with one vector.

```
a = np.array(np.arange(0, 4, 1))
```

I want to get a multiplicaton that results in a matrix like

```
 | 0  1  2  3  4
-| - - - - - - - 
0| 0  0  0  0  0
1| 0  1  2  3  4
2| 0  2  4  6  8
3| 0  3  6  9 12
4| 0  4  8 12 16
```

with the following i always get a scalar:

```
a*a
a.dot(a)
a.T*a
a*a.T
a.T.dot(a)
a.dot(a.T)
a.transpose()*a
```

Comment: `T`, transposes axes.  `a` is 1d.  shape (5,). `a.T` does change anything!

Comment: `np.arange(...)` produces an array.  No need to wrap it in another `np.array` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Convert NumPy vector to 2D array / matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33480985/convert-numpy-vector-to-2d-array-matrix)

```
>>> a = a[:,np.newaxis]                                                                                                                       
>>> a * a.T                                                                                                                                   
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 2, 4, 6],
       [0, 3, 6, 9]])
```

Comment: Or just `a[:, np.newaxis] * a`.  `np.outer(a,a)` is another option.

Answer (score 1):

an even better solution woud be

```
a = np.array([np.arange(0, 4, 1)])
a*a.T
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 2, 4, 6],
       [0, 3, 6, 9]])
```