# Expanding numpy array dimension with [:,newaxis] vs reshape(-1,1)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, dimensions

I was looking for a way to convert a complex array to a 2D float array in place and found this:

```
> print np.empty(10, dtype='complex128').reshape(-1,1).view(dtype='float64').shape
> (10,2)
```

Interestingly, using [:,newaxis] to add the extra dimension fails:

```
> print np.empty(10, dtype='complex128')[:,np.newaxis].view(dtype='float64').shape
> ValueError: new type not compatible with array.
```

This related thread discusses that both `reshape` and `newaxis` create a view but there are differences in how the strides are set:

[Numpy: use reshape or newaxis to add dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28385666/numpy-use-reshape-or-newaxis-to-add-dimensions)

How does this creating a float view on a complex array?

Comment: What version of python / numpy do you use? Both work similar for me using `Python2.7.12` with `numpy1.12.0`. Also in your example you just wrote `newaxis` without referring to numpy aka `np`. Maybe `newaxis` is bound to something else in your code?

Comment: @a_guest I'm on `numpy1.11.3`. Also, I corrected the code to include `np.`

Comment: Maybe that's a bug or they changed the way views of arrays work. Interestingly applying an additional `np.array` to the broadcasted array makes it work: `np.array(np.empty(10, dtype='complex128')[:,np.newaxis]).view(dtype='float64').shape`. I suggest upgrading to the latest release of numpy.