# np.reshape(x, (-1,1)) vs x[:, np.newaxis]

Tags: python, numpy

I am reading source code of an open source project recently. When the programmer wanted to convert a row vector like `array([0, 1, 2])` to a column vector like `array([[0], [1], [2]])`, `np.reshape(x, (-1,1))` was used. 
In the comment, it says reshape is necessary to preserve the data contiguity against vs `[:, np.newaxis]` that does not.

I tried the two ways, it seems like they will return the same results. Then what does the data contiguity preservation mean here?

Comment: Some part of this story is getting lost in the retelling. (For example, the parts about a "row vector" seem incorrect; an actual 1-by-whatever row vector would respond differently to these operations.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both ways return views of the exact same data, therefore the 'data contiguity' is likely a non-issue as the data is not change, only the view is changed.  See [Numpy: use reshape or newaxis to add dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28385666/numpy-use-reshape-or-newaxis-to-add-dimensions).

However there might be a practical advantage of using `.reshape((-1,1))`, as it will reshape the array into 2d array regardless of the original shape.  For `[:, np.newaxis]`, the result will depend on the original shape of the array, considering these:

```
In [3]: a1 = np.array([0, 1, 2])

In [4]: a2 = np.array([[0, 1, 2]])

In [5]: a1.reshape((-1, 1))
Out[5]: 
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2]])

In [6]: a2.reshape((-1, 1))
Out[6]: 
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2]])

In [7]: a1[:, np.newaxis]
Out[7]: 
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2]])

In [8]: a2[:, np.newaxis]
Out[8]: array([[[0, 1, 2]]])
```